# Problema para validar un input que tenga que ser si o si un Flotante Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, excepciones, input

tengo una consulta con respecto a como validar un input que tenga que devolver si o si un flotante

Estoy haciendo un pequeño programa para calcular la masa corporal de una persona (peso / altura**2).

Mi problema es el siguiente:

```
 import sys 
try:
     peso = int(input("colocar su peso en numeros Entero "))
     altura = float(input("colque su altura en numeros decimales :) "))
     indiceMasaCorporal = peso / altura**2
     print(indiceMasaCorporal)


except (ValueError, TypeError, IndexError):
     print("hay un error al colocar alguno de los parametros")
     print(f"es un error de tipo {sys.exc_info()[0]}")
```

Cuando al input -peso- le paso un entero, no hay ningún problema y cuando le paso al mismo input -peso-, un flotante, me lanza un "ValueError". Hasta acá va todo bien, entiendo que es un "ValueError" porque peso esta esperando un entero y si le devuelvo un flotante se genera el problema

Ahora el problema viene con el input -altura-. Siguiendo la lógica del input -peso- al devolverle al input -altura- un numero flotante el ejercicio se resuelve de manera correcta PERO cuando le devuelvo un numero entero NO ME SALE EL "ValueError" pese a que -altura- espera un flotante

Lo que no entiendo es porque el input -peso- solamente me acepta enteros(como teóricamente seria) y el input -altura- me acepta tanto enteros como flotantes

Comment: nop, no es que "espere" un flotante, sino que transforma el string a un `float`, si el número no puede ser transformado al tipo de dato que quieres entonces se genera el `ValueError`

Comment: Un entero es un flotante con parte decimal = 0.

Comment: @Christian. Estuve revisando a partir de tu explicación y sigo sin comprender que sucede. Siguiendo tu lógica, al pasarle al input -peso- un flotante, no tendría que haber ningún error ya que el posible transformar ese flotante a un entero (por ejemplo si le pasara el 7.3 me devolveria un 7), y pese a que es posible esa conversión, me sale un "ValueError"

Por otro lado, eso no pasa con el input -altura_

A lo que voy es que con el input -peso- me salta un error cuando trata de convertir un flotante a un entero pero eso mismo no sucede con el input -altura-, que me acepta ambos tipos

Comment: NO puedes convertir una cadena como "10.0" o "7.3" a entero usando solo la funcion int. Int solo convierte cadenas que representan numeros sin parte decimal. Por eso el ValueError. En cambio, la funcion float no necesita la parte decimal para hacer la conversion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes incorporar el input altura en un bucle while que compruebe que ingresaste un punto decimal de la siguiente forma:

```
try:
    peso = int(input("colocar su peso en numeros Entero "))
    while True:
        altura = input("colque su altura en numeros decimales :) ")
        if "." in altura:
            altura = float(altura)
            break
        else: 
            print("debes ingresar un numero decimal")            
    indiceMasaCorporal = peso / altura**2
    print(indiceMasaCorporal)
```

Comment: Tu código no cubre el caso de que el usuario ingrese varias letras y un punto. O varios puntos. Por ejemplo ocurriría un error si el usuario ingresa "aaa.com" o "...". Si quieres validar un numero decimal sin usar un try-except lo mejor es o hacer una función validadora o usar expresiones regulares (yo optaría por lo segundo).

Comment: Siempre debes usar try-except para validar enteros y flotantes. Nunca sabes que va a digitar el usuario.

Comment: @matias silva Muchas gracias por la respuesta hermano, me esclarecio bastante el panorama. Ahora tengo una buena herramienta para afrontar en el futuro problemáticas similares

Comment: @matias silva De todos modos me quedo una duda con respecto al (True) que le colocaste al while. Estuve probando cambiar ese True por cualquier otro valor -un string, un numero entero e incluso un flotante- y en todos los casos el algoritmo me funciono. Mi duda es porque elegiste utilizar el True como parametro del while? Es algun tipo de convension o es por algo mas en particular? Ademas tengo otra duda: cuando coloco en el parametro del while un False, ahi si me da un error. A que se debe?

Comment: @Khuranes el bucle while se va a repetir siempre y cuando la expresión que lo acompañe sea verdadera (True), si ingresas sólo un dato, ya sea un string, un int o un float, el resultado de la expresión será verdadero, por lo que de todos modos se ejecutará el bucle, pero para no darle datos que no tienen importancia o contexto dentro del codigo, es preferible simplemente darle el True sin más. Sin embargo si le das False al bucle while, este no se ejecutará, como si no existiera

Comment: @matiassilva Claro! Gracias por la ayuda broder, me sacaste todas las dudas